# Swiftでpointer being freed was not allocatedを解決する手段は？

Tags: swift, xcode6

Swiftを使用してアプリを作成しています。
METALを利用してGPGPUを試みているのですが、GPUから値を得た後に、
下記のエラーが表示され、プログラムが止まります。

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x102ca4000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

自分なりには調べているつもりなのですが、何が原因が特定できません。
メッセージの通り、malloc_error_breakをセットしてみたのですが、
止まるところはほぼ変わらず、その解析の仕方も分かりません。

せめて、object 0x102ca4000が何を示しているのかが、
分かれば少しは要因を解析できそうだと思うのですが、それを調べる方法も分かりません。

問題解決に向けて、助言をいただければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

コード全部を載せるのもどうかと思い、このような形で質問していますが、
コードを記載すべきであれば、そのようにご指導いただければと思います。
（現在の自分では、原因のありそうなところだけピックアップすることが
難しそうなので、全部載せるようなことになりそうです。そのようにして
よいかどうか、のご意見でもいただければ幸いです。）

追記１；
コードを載せたが方がよいとのコメントをいただきましたので、[Gist](https://gist.github.com/AppleDeveloper37/6c5d7ca7aa2223b5f57b)に載せました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記２；
残念ながら、まだ問題は解決されていませんが、今の所の状況を追記しておきます。

```
 var outptr = outputVectors.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer({
 ptr -> UnsafeMutablePointer<FloatVector> in
 return ptr.baseAddress
 })

 var resultData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: outputBuffer.contents(), length: vectorsByteLength)
 resultData.getBytes(outptr, length: vectorsByteLength)
```

への変更では、エラー表示に変更はありませんでした。

偶然見つけられたのですが、上記object 0x102ca4000が指し示しているものが判明しました。
resultData: NSDataインスタンスのようです。
まだ調査中ですが、コメントいただいているごとく、C(C++)とのやりとりのところに問題が
あるのかも知れません。

ここで述べるべきではないのかも知れませんが、当方、昨年６月からObjecive-Cを
プログラム言語として、まともに勉強し始めたという状況もあり、METALのshading言語がObjective-Cと異なるC++系とのことで、そこを触るだけでも、かなり四苦八苦しております。
引き続き、ご助言をいただければと思います。

Comment: ソースコードは、あったほうが回答は付きやすいと思います。コードが長い場合は[Gist](https://gist.github.com/)などを使ってください。

Comment: `METAL`には詳しくないのですが、`UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`から`Array<FloatVector>`に直接データ列をコピーするのは大丈夫なのでしょうか？Cの`float[]`からSwiftの`Array`に直接コピーしたらインスタンスが壊れるような気がするのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

問題が解決しましたので、自己回答します。
追記２で問題の対象として判明したresultDataについて、

```
var resultData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: outputBuffer.contents(),
length: vectorsByteLength)
```

を

```
var resultData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: outputBuffer.contents(),
length: vectorsByteLength, freeWhenDone: false)
```

に変更することでエラーが発生しなくなり、問題が解決しました。
問題の箇所が特定できたことにより、解決策に結びつきました。
回答が分かると、エラーの記載も分かるのですが・・・。